# How to change my helper function so that is collects the results of the parallel processing tasks

Tags: kotlin, parallel-processing, forkjoinpool

I wrote this helper function, so that I can easily process a list in parallel and only continue code execution when all the work is done. It works nicely when you don't need to return a result.

*(I know it isn't the best practice to create new pools every time, it can be easily moved out, but I wanted to keep the examples simple.)*

```kotlin
fun recursiveAction(action: () -> Unit): RecursiveAction {
    return object : RecursiveAction() {
        override fun compute() {
            action()
        }
    }
}

fun <T> List<T>.parallelForEach(parallelSize: Int, action: (T) -> Unit) {
    ForkJoinPool(parallelSize).invoke(recursiveAction {
        this.parallelStream().forEach { action(it) }
    })
}
```

Example use:

```kotlin
val myList: List<SomeClass> [...]
val parallelSize: Int = 8

myList.parallelForEach(parallelSize) { listElement ->
   //Some task here
}
```

Is there any way to make a similar helper construct for when you want to collect the results back into a list?

I know I have to use a RecursiveTask instead of the RecursiveAction, but I couldn't manage to write a helper function like I had above to wrap it.

I'd like to use it like this:

```kotlin
val myList: List<SomeClass> [...]
val parallelSize: Int = 8

val result: List<SomeClass> = myList.parallelForEach(parallelSize) { listElement ->
   //Some task here
}
```

Alternatively, is there a simpler way to do this alltogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [JeffMurdock](https://www.reddit.com/user/JeffMurdock/) over on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/fvxd1a/question_how_to_change_my_helper_function_so_that/fmp6cqe/?context=3)

```
fun <T> recursiveTask(action: () -> T): RecursiveTask<T> {
    return object : RecursiveTask<T>() {
        override fun compute(): T {
            return action()
        }
    }
}

fun <T, E> List<T>.parallelForEach(parallelSize: Int, action: (T) -> E): List<E> {
    val pool = ForkJoinPool(parallelSize)
    val result = mutableListOf<ForkJoinTask<E>>()
    for (item in this) {
        result.add(pool.submit(recursiveTask {
            action(item)
        }))
    }
    return result.map { it.join() }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    list.parallelForEach(3) { it + 2 }.forEach { println(it) }
}
```